# Is there a way to prevent XML from outputting superfluous XML data after serialisation?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, serialization

Upon serialising some sets of data to and from XML- back into my application and then displaying on my GUI, I'm getting some strange XML being output which I suspect has something to do with  my attributes perhaps, but I'm not certain. This consequently outputs on my user GUI, which is unfavourable. I've attempted to clean up the XML code post-serialisation, but the problem persists the next time I boot the program which is very strange.

For some context, my program serialises 3 arrays which hold string data and stores them as XML.

Upon booting the program, the application de-serialises the 3 separate XML files and passes the string values into some user controls, namely the 'Content' properties of some buttons.

My properties to serialize:

```
/// <summary>
/// A public accessor to access the private tasks' name field.
/// </summary>
[XmlAttribute]
public string[] TaskName
{
    get
    {
        this.TaskName = this.taskNameArray;
        return this.taskNameArray;
    }
    set
    {
        this.taskNameArray = value;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// A public accessor to access the private tasks field.
/// </summary>
[XmlAttribute]
public string[] TasksBody
{
    get
    {
        this.TasksBody = this.tasksArray;
        return this.tasksArray;
     }
     set
     {
        this.tasksArray = value;
     }

}

/// <summary>
/// A public accessor to access the private task category field.
/// </summary>
[XmlAttribute]
public string[] TasksCategory
{
    get
    {
         this.TasksCategory = this.tasksCategoryArray;
         return this.tasksCategoryArray;
    }
    set
    {
         this.tasksCategoryArray = value;
    }
 }
```

and a sample of the XML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<string>Ahn Jung Jae</string>
<string>  &amp;amp;lt;string&amp;amp;gt;NONE&amp;amp;lt;/string&amp;amp;gt; 
</string>
<string>  &amp;amp;lt;string&amp;amp;gt;NONE&amp;amp;lt;/string&amp;amp;gt; 
</string>
<string>  &amp;amp;lt;string&amp;amp;gt;NONE&amp;amp;lt;/string&amp;amp;gt; 
</string>
```

I've tried some post-serialisation XML cleaning-up via `ToString().SubString()`, but the issue persists after I re-boot the program. Any insight into preventing the weird XML would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: Below is additional code in my program to help give some context, as requested- I have two main classes in mt program: MainWindow.cs and Tasks.cs -

This method below is in the Tasks.cs class and populates the array properties:

```
        /// <summary>
    /// This method assigns the passed information of the tasks to their respective arrays.
    /// </summary>
    public void AssignParametersToArray(bool update)
    {
        // Assign parameters to array field values.
        // There needs to be an index that keeps track of the latest number of task entries,
        // as entries are: listed in an array, so lack the 'Add' function and
        // entries are updated at run-time, dynamically, so an inherent loop would not work.

        // If there are no elements in the specified slot of the array,
        // then the array slot is free to be populated.
        if (update == false)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < this.TasksBody.Length; x++)
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.tasksArray[x]))
                {
                    // Task Body
                    this.tasksArray[x] = this.tasks;
                    this.TasksBody[x] = this.tasksArray[x];//[this.TasksBodyCounterProperty]; // This step should update automatically via an event, eventually.
                    this.TasksBodyCounterProperty++;
                }

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.tasksCategoryArray[x]))
                {
                    // Task Category.
                    this.tasksCategoryArray[x] = this.tasksCategory;
                    this.TasksCategory[x] = this.tasksCategoryArray[x]; // This step should update automatically via an event, eventually.
                    this.TasksCategoryCounterProperty++;
                }

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.taskNameArray[x]))
                {
                    // Task Names.
                    this.taskNameArray[x] = this.taskName;
                    this.TaskName[x] = this.taskNameArray[x]; // This step should update automatically via an event, eventually.
                    this.TasksNameCounterProperty++;

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

These methods are also in the Tasks.cs class. They are the serialisation and deserialisation routines:

```
/// <summary>
    /// This function serializes all the task information into an XML document.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">This signifies the object type. For this routine, parameters are of type string.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="taskBody">Parameter that holds the array that holds all the task body content.</param>
    /// <param name="taskCategory">Parameter that holds the array that holds all the task category content.</param>
    /// <param name="taskName">Parameter that holds the array that holds all the task name content.</param>
    /// <param name="taskCategoryFilePath">The filepath upon which to create the destination for file category XML file.</param>
    /// <param name="taskNameFilePath">The filepath upon which to create the destination for file name XML file.</param>
    /// <param name="taskBodyFilePath">The filepath upon which to create the destination for file body XML file.</param>
    private void Serialize<T>(string[] taskBody, string[] taskCategory, string[] taskName, string taskCategoryFilePath, string taskNameFilePath, string taskBodyFilePath)
    {
        // Create 3 seperate memory streams, one for each
        // file destination of the tasks.
        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream stream3 = new MemoryStream();

        // Create an XML document and serializer object.
        XmlDocument xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.TasksBody.GetType());

        // Loop through this functionality 3 times,
        // recursively serializing task category, name and body arrays.
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                // Switch-Case through index values, writing to each respective stream for
                // the relevant task content.
                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:

                        serializer.Serialize(stream1, this.TasksCategory);
                        stream1.Position = 0;
                        xmlDocument.Load(stream1);
                break;
                    case 1:

                        serializer.Serialize(stream2, this.TaskName);
                        stream2.Position = 0;
                        xmlDocument.Load(stream2);
                break;
                    case 2:
                        serializer.Serialize(stream3, this.TasksBody);
                        stream3.Position = 0;
                        xmlDocument.Load(stream3);
                break;
                }

                switch (i)
                {
                    case 0:
                        xmlDocument.Save(taskCategoryFilePath);
                        stream1.Flush();
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        xmlDocument.Save(taskNameFilePath);
                        stream2.Flush();
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        xmlDocument.Save(taskBodyFilePath);
                        stream3.Flush();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void Deserialize<T>()
    {
        this.tasks = string.Empty;

        // Create 3 seperate memory streams, one for each
        // file destination of the tasks.
        MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream stream2 = new MemoryStream();
        MemoryStream stream3 = new MemoryStream();

        T returnObject = default(T);

        // Locate the target file path of the XML files storing the task information. 
        string taskCategoryFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).ToString() + "taskCategory.txt";
        string taskNameFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).ToString() + "taskName.txt";
        string taskBodyFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory).ToString() + "taskBody.txt";

        // Define a limit for the following loop.
        int taskTypeIndex = 3;

        // Define a buffer to hold a filepath.
        string filePathBuffer = string.Empty;

        // Loop three times, deserializing the data in each XML file.
        for (int i = 0; i < taskTypeIndex; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    filePathBuffer = taskCategoryFilePath;
                }
                else if (i == 1)
                {
                    filePathBuffer = taskNameFilePath;
                }
                else if (i == 2)
                {
                    filePathBuffer = taskBodyFilePath;
                }
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePathBuffer))
                {
                    // Declare a new Xml Document and Serializer object.
                    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
                    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(this.tasks.GetType());//this.TasksCategory.GetType());
                    //StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(filePathBuffer);
                    //XmlReader xmlReader = new XmlReader();

                    // Assign the deserialized inforamtion to the respective
                    // properties.
                    if (i == 0)
                    {
                        //XElement root = XDocument.Load(stream1).Root;
                        //serializer.Deserialize(streamReader, "UTF-8"); //(stream1, this.TasksCategory);

                        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
                        {
                            //if (reader.ReadLine() != "NIL")
                            //{
                                this.TasksCategory[x] = reader.ReadLine();
                            ///}
                            //else
                            //{
                            //    break;
                            //}
                        }

                        //serializer.Deserialize(stream1);
                        //stream1.Position = 0;
                        document.Load(filePathBuffer);

                        stream1.Flush();



                        //foreach (string item in this.TasksCategory)
                        //this.TasksCategory = (string)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);
                        //item = (string)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader);

                        //serializer.Serialize(stream1, this.TasksCategory);
                        //stream1.Position = 0;
                        //xmlDocument.Load(stream1);
                    }
                    else if (i == 1)
                    {

                        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
                        {
                            //if (reader.ReadLine() != "  <string>NIL</string>")
                            //{
                                this.TaskName[x] = reader.ReadLine();
                            //}
                            //else
                            //{
                            //    break;
                            //}
                        }

                        //serializer.Deserialize(stream2);
                        //stream2.Position = 0;
                        document.Load(filePathBuffer);

                        stream2.Flush();
                    }
                    else if (i == 2)
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
                        {
                            //if (reader.ReadLine() != "NIL" || reader.ReadLine() != "  < string > &lt; string&gt; NIL & lt;/ string & gt;</ string >" || reader.ReadLine() != "  <string>NIL</string>")
                            //{
                                this.TasksBody[x] = reader.ReadLine();
                            ///}
                            //else
                            ////{
                            //    break;
                            //}
                        }

                        //serializer.Deserialize(stream3);
                        //stream3.Position = 0;
                        document.Load(filePathBuffer);

                        stream3.Flush();
                    }

                    //returnObject = (T)serializer.Deserialize(streamReader); //

                    reader.Close();
                } 
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error loading the tasks:" + ex.ToString());
            }

            this.CleanUpXML();
        }
    }
```

There are a couple comments I left in for personal reference. If you need more info please do let me know, or if anything is unclear with my code.

Also, I wrote the AssignParametersToArray() method quite a while ago and I'm sure the quality of the code can be improved- I left it there in this post just incase it highlights where exatly I'm going wrong, perhaps.

Comment: The XML does not look like the serialization of the class you showed, Can you please post the code you use for creating the XML?

Comment: Out of curiosity: What is the line `this.TaskName = this.taskNameArray;` etc. in the getters for? This is effectively a no-op.

Comment: Post the code that populates these arrays and the code that serializes. What you've posted here isn't enough to explain how the xml file is built

Comment: The data is being encoded as HTML (not XML).  I think something is wrong with the this.tasksArray.

Comment: Hey guys, I've edited my original post to include the method that populates the arrays as well as the serialisation routines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
var emptyNamespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(new[] { XmlQualifiedName.Empty });
```

and then in your `Serialize()` method :

```
Serializer.Serialize(Stream, object, emptyNamespaces);
```

Also, you need to do:

```
XmlWriterSettings XmlSettings = new XmlWriterSettings();
XmlSettings .Indent = true;
XmlSettings .OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
```

and then pass it to xml Writer

Comment: I'll go ahead and give that a shot then update you on the results- I wont be able to do it at this moment as I'll be away from coding on my laptop, but I'm just letting you know I've acknowledged your post- then I'll reply with what happened a little later today when I have the opportunity to code. Check out my edit also of the original post, I included the serialisation routines I wrote.

Comment: Hey guys sorry for the delayed response. So Mohamad, I implemented your solution into my serialisation routine regarding the XmlWriterSettings, as well as leaving my XML cleanup-code. There was an instance where I was still getting the strange XML, but also a situation when I didn't before I changed some things in my code- so I think your answer is the closest to the ideal, if not already. I'm not getting the issue anymore after a bit of testing, so thanks everyone for the help- much appreciated.